# How to execute SQL Server Agent Jobs which are listed in SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to store all the SQL Server Agent Jobs in Table name and want to execute them based on their loading frequency.

```
CREATE TABLE Maintainance
(
SQLJobName varchar(100), --SQL Job Name which needs to be executed
Frequency varchar(50), -- It can be Daily, Monthly, Weekly, Yearly
ManualRunDate date,  --If Frequency is not given need to execute on this date
LastRunDate datetime, -- If job ran successful it will put the date and time
IsSucceed bit, --1 for Success 0 for fail
Email nvarchar(50) -- email address
)
```

I want to execute these jobs using TSQL. Also there could be more than one job into the table which needs to run. If 1st job failed it should email the person which listed in the table and it will execute next job. How can I do that using cursor or just While loop in sql?

```
declare cur cursor for
select Frequency from Maintainance

declare @x int
open cur
fetch next from cur into @x

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = @job_name

    fetch next from cur into @x
END
```

If you have any other suggestion that this can be done better way please do not hesitate to give me an idea.

Comment: Can I ask why you're semi-manually executing jobs rather than scheduling these jobs to run according to your needs?  Mind you, the inherent benefit of a job is that you're able to schedule them and react to an event, whether that is a failure or a success.

Comment: There are multiple jobs and the requirement is to create table and put the different job names into the table and some job  needs to fetch the date from table and execute on that date. Instead of looking history we can just check the table when the job ran and when it will run next.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you're not attempting to execute the job manually?  Your goal is to query the history of the jobs in your table?  If you're trying to achieve any type of job schedule override, I would revisit your requirements since that's the job of a job: to schedule the execution of a stored procedure.

Comment: I want to execute the job based on the loading frequency in the table. If it says daily it needs to be executed daily. I do not want to schedule jobs when i create the job. I want to just created them and run them based on maintenance table frequency.

Comment: >>Instead of looking history we can just check the table when the job ran and when it will run next.<<  You can query job history just the same way. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2850/querying-sql-server-agent-job-history-data/

Comment: but is there anyway i can store job names in table and execute using frequency other than job schedule  ?

Answer (score 1):

a) Create a proc that runs through list of procs with appropriate `frequency` value, executes them and updates `lastrun` column.

1. Make an argument `@frequency` in it, pass it form outside.
2. Filter your proc list with this argument
3. Loop through list of procs with this "frequency" and run procs

e.g.

```
alter proc dbo.RunProcs
  @Frequency varchar(50)
as
begin
  declare @crProcs cursor 

  set @crProcs = cursor fast_forward for
  select m.ProcName
  from dbo.Maintainance m
  where m.Frequency = @Frequency
  order by 1

  ...
  while @@fetch_status = 0
  beign
      begin try
        exec @ProcName
        ...
        update -> succeded
        ...
      end try
      begin catch
        ...
        update -> failed
        ...
      end catch
    fetch ...
  end

  return 1
end
```

b) Create scheduled jobs to run this proc

1. Create a job **"DAILY PROCS"**, assign a schedule to this job to make it run every day.

   Add a job-step with T-SQL:
   `exec dbo.RunProcs @Frequency = 'day'`
2. Create a job **"WEEKLY PROCS"**, assign a schedule to this job to make it run every week

   Add a job-step with T-SQL:
   `exec dbo.RunProcs @Frequency = 'week'`
3. Create a job **"MONTHLY PROCS"**, assign a schedule to this job to make it run every month

   Add a job-step with T-SQL:
   `exec dbo.RunProcs @Frequency = 'month'`